# Django: Sum of columns of child table with unique key passed by Main table

Tags: django, django-views

I have a Main table which pass foreign key to its child table. I want to show list of all items from Main table with sum of columns coming from Child table.

How to do it in Django queryset? Please help.

**Models.py**

```
class serviceinvoice(models.Model):
    user=models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,related_name='invoice')    
    invoice_number=models.PositiveIntegerField()
    #invoice_no = models.CharField(max_length = 500, default = increment_invoice_number, null = True, blank = True)
    invoice_date = models.DateField()
    invoice_receivable=models.ForeignKey(Receivables,null=True)
    #total_amount=models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2,max_digits=20)
    #total_amountwithtax=models.FloatField()
    company_det=models.ForeignKey(Company,related_name='companydetails')


    class Meta:
        unique_together = (("user", "invoice_number"),)
        ordering=('-invoice_number',) 

    def __str__(self):
        return self.invoice_number

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('invoice:editinvoice', args=[self.invoice_number])

class serviceinvoiceitems(models.Model):
    user=models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,related_name='serviceinvoiceitem')
    invoice_number=models.ForeignKey(serviceinvoice,related_name='serviceitems1')
    Product=models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    UOM=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    Quantity=models.FloatField()
    Rate=models.FloatField()
    Tax_rate=models.FloatField()
    Total_sale=models.FloatField()
    Sales_tax=models.FloatField()
    Total_billamount=models.FloatField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.invoice_number
```

**views.py**

```
 @login_required
def inv_list(request):
    invoice_list=serviceinvoice.objects.filter(user=request.user)
    totallist=serviceinvoice.objects.annotate(sum_list=Sum('serviceitems1__Total_sale'))
    return render(request,'account/invoicelist.html',{'invoice_list':invoice_list,'totallist':totallist})
```

So far in views I am able to filter list of invoices for a user, but how do i get total of each invoice from sub model ie serviceinvoiceitems.

> Tried something and passing `{{ totallist.sum_list }}` in template but
>   shows nothing.

Comment: You'll need to show more details. What do the models look like? What do you have so far?

Comment: @DanielRoseman updated question.

Answer (score 0):

Annotate and aggregation in django can be kind of twitchy. Try opening a `manage.py shell` and playing with your queryset `serviceinvoice.objects.all().annotate(sum_list=Sum(...)` and take a look at a couple of the results from it to verify it's giving back what you expect. That cuts out all the possible problems of templates and views not doing what you expect.

If this is giving strange results, take a look at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/aggregation/#values
Putting a `.values()` before an annotate changes the `GROUP BY` that the ORM generates, which usually is the cause of problems for people.